# How to verify if a 2D array/grid is n^2*n^2

Tags: java, arrays

How would one go about verifying if a 2d array is a n<sup>2</sup>*n<sup>2</sup> grid? Basically verify its a valid grid for Sudoku. So a 4*4 (2<sup>2</sup>*2<sup>2</sup>) grid should be true, as well as 9*9 (3<sup>2</sup>*3<sup>2</sup>). Im guessing I should take the length of each D of array, and check if theyre a square. But it cant be any square. So Im mentally stuck. Please dont just say its been asked before and link a sudoku solver question from the past, as I just want to verify if it a valid grid for playing sudoku (for now). And all the past questions ive seen always verify the contents of a 9*9, not check the actual size of the grid.

so far all ive got is

```
public Sudoku(int[][] g) {
theGrid = g;
}
private int[][] theGrid;

public boolean isValid()  {
if (theGrid.length == 0)
  return true;
if(theGrid[0].length!=theGrid[1].length)//sides arent the same length
  return false;
}
```

Any help appreciated. Thanks

Comment: `It can't be any square` - What do you mean?

Comment: @nondestructive like a 4*4 and 9*9 is valid, but a 5*5 is not

Comment: That's what I thought you meant. Your wording is a bit unclear. From that section, it sounds like the lengths of the two dimensions can't be any square, but you mean the total number of elements can't be any square, right?

Comment: I've seen Sudoku games using a 6x6 grid. e.g. [here](http://www.sudokuweb.org/easy-sudoku-6x6-for-kids/) - are you sure you only wish to allow n^2 sizes?

Answer (score 1):

Your validation function would be something like this:

```
public boolean isValid() {
    if ( theGrid.length == 0 ) {
        return true;
    }

    if ( theGrid.length != theGrid[ 0 ].length ) {//sides arent the same length
        return false;
    }

    final int n = theGrid.length;
    final double sqrt = Math.sqrt( n );

    return ( ( int ) sqrt ) == sqrt;

}
```

Comment: what about this ? ``int[][] grid = new int[9][9];    grid[3] = new int[10];``

Comment: It is a trade-off between performance and accuracy of validation.

Answer (score 0):

So given the fact that the `array[][]` in java can have different row sizes, it's better to check for every row:

```
static boolean isValid(int[][] array) {
    if(array.length == 0) return false;

    double sqrt = Math.sqrt(array.length);
    int x = (int) sqrt;

    if(Math.pow(sqrt,2) != Math.pow(x,2)) return false;

    return Arrays.stream(array).filter(ints -> ints.length != array.length).count() == 0;
}
```